# button on Directive (AngularJS )

Tags: angularjs

I want to initialize a button in my directive but call a function from controller while using that directive.

I have something like this, 
directive: 
html:  Button 
JS: MethodOnClick : '&'

while calling directive I have, 
html: MethodOnClick = "method()"
JS: @scope.method = function(){}

It does not work, the function @scope.method is not executed at all. Can some one please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `ng-click="method()`". `MethodOnClick` isn't an valid event for a button. It's a little hard to see what you're asking - post the relevant code and it'll be easier to help you.